# Where is the log file for the DSL connection on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, adsl, logging

My DSL connection drops very frequently and I want to investigate the reason. I thought of checking the log file if it contains some clue about it, but I'm unable to locate it. Google did not help.

Can you tell me where the ADSL log file is for Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the connection is dropped by the modem so, unless you have an internal modem, it's on your modem/router and you could access it by its web interface using http://itsIP/ (generally http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.0.1)

If the connection is dropped by your computer (internal modem/network card):

- Click Start, and then click Control Panel. Click Performance and Maintenance, then click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Computer Management. Or, open the MMC containing the Event Viewer snap-in.
- In the console tree, click Event Viewer / System Log

Answer (score 0):

The DSL connection log would be on your modem/router, not on your XP computer.

What country are you in?  I know over here in the UK, ADSL microfilters are required to filter out noise on the line (I just noticed the ADSL tag).  I would strongly recommend replacing the microfilter and see if this helps before trying anything else.

Failing this, you would be best off speaking to your internet provider who should have the ability to check the logs their end and run line tests to determine the root cause of the problem.

One question, are you connecting to your modem/router wirelessly or with a cable?  If wirelessly, try with a cable.  If with a cable, are there any other computers in your house/office that you can test with to rule out a problem with an individual computer?

Comment: Cable. I'll try with an other computer